Why doesn't my toggle button work in Angular?
In my application, the navbar seems to be working correctly- the UI is showing up correctly, adjusts correctly based on screen size, etc, but for some reason, the toggle button doesn't work. I tried inspecting element, but no errors show up. I made sure all the correct dependencies were installed, and added the correct paths to my angular.json file, however, it still isn't working. I also redid ng serve multiple times to see if I just needed to rebuild the app again.
angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "better-posture": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/better-posture",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kB",
                  "maximumError": "1MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kB",
                  "maximumError": "4kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "better-posture:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "better-posture:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

app.component.html
<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page">Camera</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page">Profile</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/stats" routerLinkActive="active" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page">Stats</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/settings" routerLinkActive="active" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page">Settings</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  

Thank you for any help!

Could u please add it in jsfiddle?

@RameshRajendran Hi, thank you for your comment. I'm not sure how to do that, I've never used jsfiddle. do you want me to add the whole project to jsfiddle? how would I do that?

Your current HTML only works in Bootstrap 4. As you tagged Bootstrap 5 in your question, Bootstrap 5 supports the data-bs-* attributes instead of data-* attributes. Reference: Bootstrap 5 migration
<button
    class="navbar-toggler"
    type="button"
    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
    data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
    aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
    aria-expanded="false"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
  >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

Besides, Bootstrap 5 requires Popper library. Either you can use the bootstrap bundle file as below:

angular.json

"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
]

Or you may refer to my previous answer on Bootstrap 5 dropdown is not working on Angular 12 for importing the Popper or alternatives. Make sure that you restart the Angular app to make it work.
Demo @ StackBlitz

thank you so much! I'm impressed that you even noticed the tag, you're a lifesaver :)
